# How can I change an endpoint that returns one object to be filterable on which properties to return?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to find the cleanest way to do this but haven't had much luck on google. I'm returning an Information object that has properties assemblies, configuration, and cassandra.

I want it to work so if I call /api/Information?filter=Assemblies,Configuration, it returns only the assemblies and configuration properties, leaving out cassandra.

I can do this currently but I'm doing it with if else statements. Is there a better approach to this, maybe with an interface?

Comment: This is exactly what GraphQL is intended to solve:

https://graphql.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for that would work for .net very well is [OData](https://www.odata.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use odata to do that it is exactly what you need.

Startup.cs should be modified like this.

```
public class Startup
{
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<yourDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("yourList"));
    services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel())
.Filter().Select());
}




public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Send "~/$odata" to debug routing if enable the following middleware
    // app.UseODataRouteDebug();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    // …
}
}
```

Controller should be like this:

```
public class InformationController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IEnumerable<Information> Get()
{
    //…your logic
}


}
```

Api
So if you do `/api/Information?Select=Assemblies,Configuration` you will only get assemblies and configuration.

Comment: The object I'm returning is not stored in a database. It is an object created in realtime when the endpoint is called, made of strings from the config. Could this approach still work?

Comment: Yes it will work with or without database, and if solution work please accept my answers. Thanks.